# Change a sortedModel in ember

Tags: ember.js, model

i have a sorted ember Model. Now i will this Model change and load new Data in. The Model has e.g. Userdata and the User clicked to 'load more' and new Data coming in this model. Badly the sortedModel has no the new data.

Has anyone any idea how this works?

He my sortedModel: `sortedModel: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortBy')`

And this is the data changing: `this.get('model').pushObjects(records.content);`

Comment: `sortedModel` - will not be recomputed when you do pushObject, it will be recalculated only when you assign new different array.

Comment: Ok, than i will try to fix this.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to solve this dynamically?

Comment: I think we can't do using the `computed.sort` macro.. You need to write your own computed property and  sorting logic like `sortedModel: Ember.computed('model.[]',function() { //return the sorted resut })`

Comment: ah yes. This is a good idea, thanks :)

This was also my first thought, I thought maybe there is still a faster and easier way.

Comment: May be you can try notifying the property change by saying `this.get('model').notifyPropertyChange()`

Answer (score 0):

Other than stated in comments `computed.sort` should observe pushes to `model`. I've written a short ember-twiddle to demonstrate that pushing to model updates sortedModel: https://ember-twiddle.com/aeedf867f42489b3118d35bfaa0f0a01?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C

Your issue might be related to array of objects you are pushing to `model` (`records.content`) but question does not include enough code to inspect that one.